# sys.stdin.name: How to return name of file python script is currently reading

Tags: python, git, filenames

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = re.sub('\$File\$', sys.stdin.name, line)
```

I have this code in my python script's main, I want to return the filename but this just returns `<stdin>`. 
Any Ideas??

Again this script is a git smudge script which should be writing the filename of the file being committed.. not the name of the python script. Which is why inspect.getfile() doesn't work here either.

Thanks

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260888/python-stdin-filename

Comment: that answer seems to be specific to linux.. i need it to work for all machines.

Comment: `git` smudge/clean filters are passed the data of a blob on their standard input. If there is a file name it takes the form of `.git/objects/17/b8361bab1a69cbaa360eafb72e57b53bb72e04`, which is not likely to be useful to you. But it's probably even more likely to be data being extracted/constructed on the fly from various pack files and deltas, in which case there isn't a real file name anyway.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I have a bunch of files with scm headers that were created by svn. I want to switch my version control over to git so that when i commit those headers change along with the commit..

///$File$
//$Date$
//$Branch$
//$Revision$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using `__name__` or `os.path.realpath(__file__)`:

If you are importing the file:

```
print __name__
```

If you are running in the file:

```
print os.path.realpath(__file__)
```

Or, using `sys`:

```
print sys.argv[0]
```

Comment: these are only printing out the name and location of my python script, not the files that I committed.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use `inspect` module:

```
echo "import inspect; print inspect.stack()[0][1]" > /tmp/foo.py
python /tmp/foo.py
/tmp/foo.py
```