# Change python code to write output from shell in different folders

Tags: python, shell

I use the following code to split a file into several hundreds different files each having 16 rows . Now I want to run this code many time and read input file and write output in separate folders, not just in the current folder. Now I run the code as:

```
python split.py < input.txt
```

But I want to do something like:

```
for i in {1..10}; do python split.py < folder${i}/input.txt ; done
```

and write those files in the corresponding folder. I can read the input file from different folders but the problem is output files are written and overwritten in the directory where I run the command. I am not sure how to fix this here `with open("ratio-{}.txt".format(i), 'w') as File:`in the code.

Here is my short code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import sys, os
import itertools

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

def convNotation(x):
    if isinstance(x, float):
        s = str(x)
    else:
        s = x
    return s.replace('e', "*^")

Values = (Line.strip() for Line in sys.stdin)
Data = list(grouper(Values, 16, 0.0))

for i in range(len(Data)):
    Conf = Data[i]
    with open("ratio-{}.txt".format(i), 'w') as File:
        for x in Conf:
            print(x, file=File)
```

Comment: This code handles reading the input. All I need to do is : python split.py < inputfile

Comment: Maybe take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260888/python-stdin-filename

Comment: So all of your inputs are in same folder but you want the output to different folders, is that right?

Comment: Aries, you are right. Now all my inputs are written one over another in the directory where I execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
f = open('output.txt','w')
print >>f, "output text"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have the all inputs in same directory with *.txt format.
And you need to create new sequential directories and put the outputs there. Instead of changing the python code, you can try running the code inside a shell script.

- The idea is to assign a sequence for your output files.
- Create new sequential directories.
- Move your outputs to those directories.

The pseudocode would looks something like this:

```
for filename in /Directory_to_input/*.txt; do
    for ((i=0; i<=10; i++)); do
           mkdir ./myfolder$i 
           python split.py < input.txt
    done
    for ((j=0; j<=10; j++)); do
          mv "output$j.txt" myfolder$j/
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think I got it now. I can do this :

```
for i in {9..13}; do (cd t${i}/m0/ && python /Users/hunululu/Projects/codes/convert-to-math.py < q1f.txt); done
```

Thanks all.